# How to ensure user input date is in correct format

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I need to ensure the user enters the date in the following format -

12/23/1993

If it's a single digit month or day, I need a leading zero included.

I need 02/04/1998 not 2/4/1998

How can I ensure that leading zeros or 2 digits are present?

This is what I have so far

```
from datetime import datetime


def validate_date(d):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False


print validate_date('02/26/2009')  # prints False
```

However, this will print true even if a single digit is entered for month/day.

Comment: You could just use a datetimepicker with the format MM/dd/yyyy which would force the correct format for you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with datetimepicker, could explain?

Comment: Sorry, didn't look at the tags and thought I was in VB.Net :(

Comment: How is the user submitting the date?

Comment: Either using command line argument or raw input. Either works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to over engineer... you can probably just check the length of the string. This will work for years between 1000-9999

```
from datetime import datetime

def validate_date(d):
    try:
        if len(d) == 10: 
            datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
            return True
        else: return False

    except ValueError:
        return False

print(validate_date('2/26/1000'))
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks! I was thinking there was just some symbol in date time that would do it but this works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever user input is, you can convert it to your required format.

```
>>> date_string = '2/4/1998'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'02/04/1998'
```

and to ensure user entered format as follows

```
def validate_date_format(date_string):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Date format should be MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this with a loop to get input from the user.

1. Prompt the user for a value (let them know how it should be formatted) and then try to cast it like you're doing.
2. If the cast succeeds then you break the loop and continue. If it fails...
3. You catch the error and display the message about an invalid format and repeat step 1. Loop until you get a valid value.

---

```python
good_value = false
value = ""

while good_value == false:
    value = input("Insert Date in format...")

    try:
        datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
        good_value = true

    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Date format invalid.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to force `strptime` to validate that there is a leading 0.  As you said, it's happy with both 2/4/1998 and 02/04/1998.  I don't know of any way to do this other than a regular expression:

```
import re
regex = r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'
if re.match(d):
    # then it matches the syntax you want
```

But you still want to use strptime to validate the input, so you don't get some mess like '99/99/0123'.

When you put it all together, you'd need something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

def validate_date(d):
    try:
        regex = r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'
        if re.match(d):
            datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
            return True

    except ValueError:
        return False

    return False
```

If you're not familiar with regexes, this is a relatively simple one.  The leading `r` tells python this is a raw string, and it shouldn't process backslashes.  `\d` means any digit, and the `{2}` and `{4}` says that it should repeat (any digit) 2 and 4 times respectively.